# Tengo problemas con la memoria del disco C usando Python

Tags: python

Buen día,

Estoy aprendiendo python para ciencia de datos, y mientras lo utilizaba en menos de un mes he consumido la totalidad de la memoria del disco C (con 200 Gb). El computador solo lo estoy utilizando para practicas de python y uso de redes sociales como youtube y gmail. Me puse a depurar la carpeta de descargas y libere algunos archivos, quitando 2 Gb pero al siguiente día con el uso python ya había consumido casi por completo la memoria liberada, tengo un disco D con 900 Gb pero creo que el problema no se solucionaría si paso la instalación de los programas en dicho disco. He estado investigando un poco pero no he encontrado nada significativo, una ayuda de parte de la comunidad de python seria genial. Gracias

Comment: Solo puedo suponer, pero quizá haya algun pyw (archivo de Python que se abre sin mostrar ninguna ventana) ejecutandose que está escribiendo algún archivo. Por ejemplo, un archivo llamado archivo.pyw con el codigo `with open("txt.txt", "w") as file: while True: file.write("a")`, que escribe la letra a en un archivo txt infinitamente.

Comment: El mini-codigo que hice en 10 segundos creó un archivo de más de 30 mb. Por lo que suponiendo que la culpa sea de Python, puede ser una buena causa. Podrías revisar si algun programita tuyo hace algo similar y ver si está ejecutandose.

Comment: Esta pagina dice como puedes hacer para encontrar los archivos más grandes en tu disco: https://www.softzone.es/windows-10/como-se-hace/encontrar-borrar-archivos-mas-ocupan/

Comment: Usa el administrador de tareas para ver si hay un script python ejecutándose en segundo plano que  no tenga ventana GUI y dar clic para elegir finalizar tarea. Es posible que el script se pueda distinguir porque tiene el icono de python

Comment: piensa amliamente, no todo puede ser culpa de python, puede que tengas algún virus :(